# Crystal Reports Formula for comparing time

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I have a requirement in Crystal reports 2008, wherein I need to create formula that filters all the records that have StartTime 12:00 AM. I have a table called Trip and a field called StartTime in that. How do I write a formula that if Trip.StartTime is "12:00 AM", do not print anything. StartTime is a datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL, you can do:

```
select
    *
from
    Table
where
    cast(StartDate as time) > '00:00:00'
```

Comment: No, but I want to create a formula in Crystal reports that does the work. Something like if({Trip.StartTime}) is "12:00 AM" then return empty string. But I do not know how to write an actual formula that does that job.

Answer (score 0):

```
if cTime({Trip.StartTime}) = cTime(00, 00, 00) then
    ""
else
    toText(cTime({Trip.StartTime});
```